# TLS Handshake Error while Creating Hyperledger Fabric Channel with Multiple Organisation Orderers

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

**Scenario:** I have two organisation with two peers in each organisation. Now, I want each organisation to provide an orderer node as well.

Below is my ***crypto-config.yaml*** file:

```
OrdererOrgs:

  - Name: Orderer1
    Domain: org1.xyz.com
    Template:
    Count: 1

  - Name: Orderer2
    Domain: org2.xyz.com
    Template:
    Count: 1
```

Below is my ***configtx.yaml*** file:

```
 - &OrdererOrg1

    Name: OrdererOrg01
    ID: Orderer1MSP
    MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/org1.xyz.com/msp
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Orderer1MSP.member')"
        Writers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Orderer1MSP.member')"
        Admins:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Orderer1MSP.admin')"

- &OrdererOrg2

    Name: OrdererOrg02
    ID: Orderer2MSP
    MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/org2.xyz.com/msp
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Orderer2MSP.member')"
        Writers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Orderer2MSP.member')"
        Admins:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Orderer2MSP.admin')"
```

Below is my ***docker-compose-cli.yaml*** file:

```
services:

     orderer.xyz.com:
        extends:
        file:   base/docker-compose-base.yaml
        service: orderer.xyz.com
        container_name: orderer.xyz.com
        networks:
         - byfn

    orderer0.xyz.com:
       extends:
       file:   base/docker-compose-base.yaml
       service: orderer0.xyz.com
       container_name: orderer0.xyz.com
       networks:
        - byfn
```

I try to create a channel with the following command:

```
peer channel create -o orderer.xyz.com:7050 -t 60s -c bay -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls true --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/org1.xyz.com/orderers/orderer0.org1.xyz.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.org1.xyz.com-cert.pem
```

I get the following **ERROR** on Orderer container logs while creating a channel:

> [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 015 TLS handshake failed with
>   error remote error: tls: bad certificate {"server": "Orderer", "remote
>   address": "172.22.0.18:48594"}

So, is it possible that for organisations providing peers, provide an orderer node as well or a separate third organisation will be providing orderer nodes (as observed in tutorials)? And why am I getting this error?

Thanks for your time and let me know If you require any further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm finally able to find the actual reason behind this issue. The issue was with the service name of orderer containers in the ***docker-compose-cli.yaml*** file. Service name should be matched with the name specified in the ***crypto-config.yaml*** file following hostname.domain pattern.

So, I changed the orderer configurations in the ***docker-compose-cli.yaml*** file like below:

```
services:

  orderer0.telco1.vodworks.com:
    extends:
      file:   base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: orderer.vodworks.com
    container_name: orderer.vodworks.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  orderer0.telco2.vodworks.com:
    extends:
      file:   base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: orderer0.vodworks.com
    container_name: orderer0.vodworks.com
    networks:
      - byfn
```

After this, I modified the `peer channel` commands in ***script.sh*** and ***utils.sh*** scripts by adding the correct name of orderers. After these couple of changes I was able to run my network successfully and verified this deployment by installing chaincodes as well.

Thanks to @arnaud-j-le-hors for the sample application which helped me out to figure out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how you defined the structure of organizations and peers in your network, but, by watching at the path you specify for the `--cacert` and the config files, it seems to me that `telco1.vodworks.com` is not specified being an orderer organization.

Overall I may ask, are you sure that the path for the `--cacert` is correct?

Comment: Sorry, "telco1.vodworks.com" is actually my "org1.xyz.com" and I have verified the path for --cacert and its correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the expert here but I'm not sure why you are trying to connect to orderer.xyz.com? I've got one setup that looks like what you're trying to do and for that you should give a name to each of the ordering nodes you want to create by adding the following lines to your crypto-config file (for both orderers):

```
Specs:
  - Hostname: orderer
```

And you should define two corresponding containers, one called orderer.org1.xyz.com and the other orderer.org2.xyz.com in your compose file.

You should then be able to create the channel by contacting orderer.org1.xyz.com.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have updated my question and added 'docker-compose-cli.yaml' file. My Orderer's container name is 'orderer.xyz.com' that's why I am creating channel by using it. So, this isn't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I got this error

```
[core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 025 TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: internal error {"server": "Orderer", "remote address": "190.22.189.42:40746"}
```

When I use a fabric sdk to connect to a Fabric Network that use TLS enabled.
To solve this you need ensure that the connection profile use the hostnameOverride propertie in Orderer section this an example

```
orderers:
```

orderer.example.com:
    url: grpcs://localhost:7050

```
# these are standard properties defined by the gRPC library
# they will be passed in as-is to gRPC client constructor
grpcOptions:
  hostnameOverride: orderer.example.com
  grpc-max-send-message-length: 15
  grpc.keepalive_time_ms: 360000
  grpc.keepalive_timeout_ms: 180000
```

Please check the next example to more information : https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java/blob/master/src/test/fixture/sdkintegration/network_configs/network-config-tls.yaml

Really I was working days in this error and finally I found the solution

To more information, fabric training,  or develop blockchain solutions to the business and goverment   based in Hyperledger Fabric in Chile and Latin America please visit [www.blockchainempresarial.com](https://www.blockchainempresarial.com)